# Odd-bit primes ratio

Tags: prime-numbers, nt.number-theory

Say that a number is an *odd-bit* number if
the count of 1-bits in its binary representation is odd.
Define an *even-bit* number analogously.
Thus $541 = 1000011101_2$ is an odd-bit number,
and $523 = 1000001011_2$ is an even-bit number.

> Are there, asymptotically, as many odd-bit primes as even-bit primes?

For the first ten primes, we have
$$
\lbrace 10, 11, 101, 111, 1011, 1101, 10001, 10011, 10111, 11101
\rbrace
$$
with 1-bits
$$
\lbrace 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4 \rbrace
$$
and so ratio of #odd to $n$ is $5/10=0.5$ at the 10-th prime.
Here is a plot of this ratio up to $10^5$:

---

[image: 10^5]


<sup>(Vertical axis is mislabeled: It is #odd/$n$.)</sup>

---

I would expect the #odd/$n$ ratio to approach $\frac{1}{2}$, except perhaps the fact that primes ($>2$) are
odd might bias the ratio.  The above plot does not suggest convergence
by the 100,000-th prime (1,299,709).

Pardon the naïveness of my question.

**Addendum**: Extended the computation to the $10^6$-th prime (15,485,863), where it still
remains 1.5% above $\frac{1}{2}$:

---

[image: 10^6]

---

Comment: The fact that primes greater than 2 are odd only biases one bit, which should have a negligible effect in the long run.  Ignoring the last bit, looking at any particular finite subset of the bits should reveal a uniform distribution by the strong form of Dirichlet's theorem and the difficult question is whether this is still true if one looks at all the bits.

Comment: I guess the 2.5% bias in favor of odd-bit primes in the first 100K is just an unexplainable fact about the distribution...?

Comment: What you call "odd-bit numbers" are often called Thue-Morse numbers. I like your terminology better, but tradition is tradition.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for the key phrase! Wikipedia says: "The Thue–Morse sequence was first studied by Eugène Prouhet in 1851,.... However, Prouhet did not mention the sequence explicitly; this was left to Axel Thue in 1906."  Quite a long and tangled history!

Comment: I thought the "odd-bit numbers" were usually called odious numbers (and the complementary set called evil numbers).

Comment: David, I thought the same thing. OEIS agrees with you (http://oeis.org/A000069) and says that the odious numbers are the indices of the 1's in the Thue-Morse sequence (http://oeis.org/A010060).

Comment: (Power outtage made my graphs disappear for three days. Sorry!)

Comment: Thanks for putting the graphs back up, it makes the question look much nicer!

Comment: It is still not obvious to me why there is a bias in favour of the odd-bit primes among the first $10^6$ primes. What am I missing?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I tried, unsuccessfully, to replicate your graph in Mathematica. My results differ significantly from yours; indeed, for instance for $n=20\times10^{3}$, the ratio of odd-bit to even-bit primes is $\frac{10693}{9307}$, i.e., $1.1489\ldots$. Can you explain how you obtained your graph?

Comment: @Klangen: I lost my $9$-yr old code, but it was easy enough to recreate. Up to $20000$, I get that exact same fraction. And if you divide #odd by $n$, $10693/20000 \approx 0.53$, which is exactly what the graph shows. I see now that I mislabled the graph as odd/even, when it is odd/$n$, which is why it is close to $\frac{1}{2}$. I will add a remark to correct.

Comment: I believe we have Berlekamp, Conway, and Guy, Winning Ways, to thank for the "odious" and "evil" terminology.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Thank you for the clarification, it makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes. This was proven in

C. Mauduit and J. Rivat, *Sur un problème de Gelfond: la somme des chiffres des nombres premiers*, Ann. Math.

I found this by searching for "evil prime" and "odious prime" in the OEIS. More precisely, they prove the **Gelfond conjecture**:

> Let $s_q(p)$ denote the sum of the digits of $p$ in base $q$.  For $m, q$ with $\gcd(m, q-1) = 1$ there exists $\sigma_{q,m} > 0$ such that for every $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have
>
> $$| \{ p \le x : s_q(p) \equiv a \bmod m \} | = \frac{1}{m} \pi(x) + O_{q,m}(x^{1 - \sigma_{q,m}})$$
>
> where $p$ is prime and $\pi(x)$ the usual prime counting function.

Comment: Beat me by 23 seconds. +1 for that.

Comment: This looks rather analogous to Chebotarev's theorem.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, the ratio approaches 1/2.  This was proven in

C. Mauduit et J. Rivat, Sur un probléme de Gelfond: la somme des chiffres des nombres premiers.

See [Three topics in additive prime number theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.0823) for exposition.  Also, the poorly-named sequences in Sloane: [A027697](http://oeis.org/A027697) and [A027699](http://oeis.org/A027699).

Comment: Thanks! There is a nice conjecture of Vladimir Shevelev embedded in the OEIS descriptions: the n-th _odius_ prime is less than the n-th _evil_ prime. I agree that these are poorly named!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Indeed. But it seems to me that several of those conjectures are "false", due to Mauduit & Rivat. For example, it cannot be true that A027699(n) - A027697(n) tends to infinity with n.

Comment: @Klangen Perhaps you could submit that as a comment to those sequences?