# Parity of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

While working on a completely different (combinatorial) problem, I ran a simple program to calculate the [parity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Parity.html) of the first ~50000 primes (number of 1s in their binary representation modulo 2). The following graph summarizes the result:

[image]

The number of primes having even parity seems to grow slower.

> Is there a math explanation ?

I looked to the correspoding [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A200246), but it doesn't provide any detail.

Comment: What does "parity" mean? The parity of the number of ones in the binary representation? If so, please say it. If not, please say it.

Comment: @IgorRivin: sorry, question edited (I had only one non-trivial definition of parity of a number in my mind :-)

Comment: It's right there on the right hand side under "Related". http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44561/odd-bit-primes-ratio

Comment: @FelipeVoloch: thanks, I didn't notice it while typing the question (or perhaps it wasn' there) :-S  ... a.k.a. the Thue-Morse numbers ...

Comment: A version of this question was earlier explored in "[Odd-bit primes ratio](http://mathoverflow.net/q/44561/6094)."

Comment: I'm confused as to what the x and y axes on the graph are.

Comment: @NateEldredge: y axis: number of primes having even (red line) or odd (black line) parity; x axis: number of primes considered (in thousands)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was shown (amongst other things) by Gel'fond that the asymptotic growth rates of the primes with even and odd parity base 2 expansions are the same:

Gelʹfond, A. O.
Sur les nombres qui ont des propriétés additives et multiplicatives données. (French)
Acta Arith. 13 1967/1968 259–265.

A more recent paper on this is due to Mauduit and Rivat.

Comment: I've noticed that most primes seem to start with a 1 in their base 2 expansion.

Comment: OK, so, asymptotically they are the same, but that doesn't rule out the possibility that odd parity up to $N$ exceeds even for all $N$. It doesn't even exclude the possibility that the difference goes to infinity. Do the published results speak to these more delicate questions?

Comment: It is known that among multiples of 3, asymptotically half of them have an even number of 1s in their binary expansion, but there is a second-order term that biases multiples of 3 towards having an even number of 1s. (At its core, this is because a multiple of 3 must have its alternating sum of bits be a multiple of 3; this is more likely when there are the same number of even-bit 1s and odd-bit 1s than when there are 3 more even-bit 1s than odd-bit 1s, etc.) ...

Comment: ... Presumably then, the bias in the above graph is due (to first-order approximation) to the fact that primes are not multiples of 3. This phenomenon has been explored by V. Shevelev (see papers on the arXiv).

Comment: It seems too that most primes end with a $1.$ It is rare to have all $1's$ but even rarer to only have that pair of $1$s.....